# Why does my app fail to find and use a file on two LINUX OS machines when knowing the URL?

Tags: linux, yii

I have a Yii MVC App. When running the app under Windows OS, the app locates and uses the needed file.

I now have 2 OS's, Linux OS's and, on one, my app finds and uses the file, and on another, it fails.

```
$this->font1 = Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/protected/extensions/TextFigletCaptcha/flf/' . $this->font1 . '.flf';
if (!file_exists($this->font1)) {
throw new Exception('Font file not found!<br/>');
}
```

What's happening ?

Comment: Could be a permission issue.

Comment: no, if i use getcwd(), it works

Comment: Looks like that is not always enough: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211928/php-file-exists-is-returning-false-even-if-file-exist-on-my-linux) question and its answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:

```
$this->font1 = Yii::app()->getBasePath(true) . '/extensions/TextFigletCaptcha/flf/' . $this->font1 . '.flf';
```

Comment: `Yii::app()->baseUrl` returns an URL, `Yii::app()->basePath` returns a path.